# Is there a way to know the username of all who zip downloaded/cloned a private repo in Github?

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to know the **username** of all who *zip
downloaded/cloned* a private repo in **Github**?

Answer (score 1):

No, GitHub does not let you see that information, not through the web page nor through the API.

Comment: Can i know any info about the person who downloaded or cloned it?

Comment: No, you can not.